# Dynamic insert/update/select mysql python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a query on a table, but values what i want to enter is dynamic. One time i want to enter 4 values in 4 columns, second time maybe i want to enter 5 values in 5 columns. 
Like :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column1 = x AND column2 = y
```

But sometime i need something like this
`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column2 = x AND column6 = y AND column1 = z`

Same at insert and update like this:

`UPDATE table_name SET column1 = x, column7 = y WHERE column9 = z`
but, columns at `SET` and `WHERE` may be more or less.
This is what i made, but number of columns is static:
`cur.execute("""UPDATE logs SET Log_Status = %s WHERE Log_Path = %s""", (value, pathLog))`
Thanks!

Comment: and where's your python code showing your attempt at doing this?

Comment: Now i have only simple code, with static numbers of columns : cur.execute("""UPDATE logs SET Log_Status = %s WHERE Log_Path = %s""", (value, pathLog)), i don't have any idea how to make dynamic columns

Comment: that belongs in your question

Answer (score 0):

In case params is a dictionary:

```
params = {'column1': 'value1', 'column2': 'value2'}
```

You can try something like this:

```
terms = ' AND '.join(f'{key} = %s' for key in params)
query = 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ' + terms
args = (params.values())
cur.execute(query, args)
```